# Deleting several features from shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, geometry, delete

I recently started working with ArcMap and Python.
I try to delete several objects from my shapefile in ArcMap. I would like to select for example the line which are too close together. I don't want to select each line separately...
Is there any chance to do this automatically using the ArcMap and Python tools?

[image]

The lines are about 5 meters apart.
I would like to get lines 10-11 meters away (so as not to change the overall shape).

Comment: You need to keep outermost lines unchanged like in your example? Why do you need to delete the lines, what is your next step?

Comment: This lines (gray) on a scale of 1:10,000 they are 5 meters away. I would like to show them for a scale of 1:25 000, but they become illegible. 
I need to get lines spaced about 11 meters apart, but keeping the overall shape.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) (backup data first), but that will affect all your lines, not only the ones Close together:

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

Or try:

1. Feature to Polygon
2. Make Feature Layer with a Query "selecting" polygons with low [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polsby%E2%80%93Popper_test): `(4*3.1415* "Shape_area")/( "Shape_length"* "Shape_length") < 0.5`, you probably want to adjust 0.5 and maybe add a maximum shape area condition to only select small polygons
3. Dissolve polygons
4. Erase lines with dissolved polygons
5. Convert dissolved polygons to lines
6. Merge output with erased lines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have one logic I think will work to solve the problem.
First define the distance which you think it is too close.

Distance=too close distance

Then use Spatial Query (Feature Within) give distance and delete the selected data.